# Get SPTImage from NSURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify, spotify-app

I'm using Spotify's new iOS SDK beta and wondering if there's a way to retrieve an `SPTImage` from an NSURL (originally extracted from the `SPTPartialAlbum.covers` property, or if the only way to retrieve it is from getting the `SPTPartialAlbum` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL options:0 error:&error];
    if (imageData) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion) completion([UIImage imageWithData:imageData]);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that while that'll work, you'll block the main thread if you don't explicitly do it on a background thread. This will provide a very bad user experience on a slow connection.